# .sql file dump returns empty tables

Tags: database, mysql, database-restore

Someone has sent me a database dump as a `.sql` file dumped using phymyadmin interface. I am trying to restore the dump using the mysql command prompt, however I keep getting empty tables. The `.sql` file creates a database before creating tables and populating them. When the empty tables message first showed up I thought it was because the database had to be created before running the script, so I created the db and ran the script again, however the tables still show up as empty set.

I tried these steps,

1. logged in as root.
2. `create database x` (this is the name of the db in the create db command in the `.sql` file)
3. `mysql x -u root -p < my_x_db.sql`
4. logged in as root
5. `show databases`
6. `use x`
7. `show tables` -- empty set

What should I do different and how can I troubleshoot this?

Thanks

Comment: errors? Check the SQL-File,..

Comment: There are no errors. What should I look for in the .sql file? Everything seems OK there.

Comment: No errors + No tables created,.. Did this ever an instruction to create tables? Without Source, we cant help, we can **only** speculate

Comment: Does the .sql file contain INSERT statements? If mysqldump was run with the -d option, there won't be any data, only table structure.

Comment: Yes, it does have create table and insert statements and a good number of records.

Comment: Is there a `USE databasename;` statement at the top of the .sql file? That's going to change the current database from 'x' to whatever is specified there. As root user, you should have privileges, you should be seeing errors if you don't have privileges, insufficient space, or whatever. You should be seeing some output. Try `mysql x -u root -p`, and then at the mysql> prompt,  type "`source mysql_x_db.sql`" and press enter.

Comment: There is a USE dbname statement.  I did try the command you outlined several times, I always get the same output, "Query OK, 0 rows affected" several times. I am totally lost...

Answer (score 0):

There was a create database statement in the .sql file. I solved this by simply commenting the statement. I had already created the database with the same name externally.